# Differentiating Stochastic Integrals (Ito Integrals)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

If I wanted to differentiate a stochastic integral, is this logic correct? $$X_t = \int_0^t B^2_s dB_s\\ dX_t = d \int_0^t B^2_s dB_s \\ dX_t = B^2_tdB_t - B^2_0dB_0 \\ 
dX_t =  B^2_tdB_t \quad (B_0 = 0) $$
Then would this follow by the same logic?
$$X_t = \int_r^t B^2_s dB_s\\ dX_t = d \int_r^t B^2_s dB_s \\ dX_t = B^2_tdB_t - B^2_rdB_r $$

I am just taking the derivative, not $\frac{d}{dt}$ so I believe Leibniz rule does not apply (unless there is a rule for this that I am unaware of).

Comment: In general, the notation $dX_t = H_t dB_t$ is *short-hand* notation for the Ito integral $X_t = X_0 +\int_0^t H_s dB_s$ (Brownian motion is not differentiable...). So, it follows that $X_t-X_r = \int_r^t H_s dB_s$ using the properties of integrals. Not sure if this answers your question...

Comment: @NapD.Lover It fuĺly answers OP's question. On top of that: that logic to subtract terms like $B^2_r\,dB_r$ is nonsense.

Comment: @NapD.Lover Yes that does, cheers

Comment: Heuristically, the ito differential $dX_t = X_{t+dt}-X_t= \int_t^{t+dt}B_s^2dB_s$ shouldn't have anything to do with $\tau$.

Answer (score 2):

$X_{t}$ is not in general differentiable in the sense of ordinary calculus.
The notation
$$
dX_{t}=B_{t}^{2}dB_{t}
$$
is equivalent to
$$
X_{t_{1}}-X_{t_{0}}=\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}B_{t}^{2}dB_{t}\qquad\text{for }t_{0}<t_{1}.
$$

On the other hand, writing
$$
dX_{t}=B_{t}^{2}dB_{t}-B_{r}^{2}dB_{r}
$$
does not really make sense.